# duration of migration from svn to tfs

Tags: svn, tfs, tfs-migration

how much time ll it take to migrate from VSS/SVN to TFS

Comment: This is a really good example of a really poorly asked question.  Try making the question into a proper question, using capitals and punctuation, and providing enough information to allow someone to answer.

Comment: It depends on how fast you are travelling.

Comment: what made you tag this "python"? I retagged it to something more relevant, although even now your question isn't too coherent

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size, speed, etc of your data